# Why are 'too less' and 'too fewer' wrong?

Tags: grammaticality

Please do NOT rephrase or rewrite   the troubling sentences below.

> ✘ 1. Why is it wrong to write: **too** fewer than everyone ?
>   ✓ 2. But it's right to write: **excessively** fewer than everyone.
>
> ✘ 3. Why is it wrong to write: **too** less than everything ?
>   ✓ 4. But it's right to write: **excessively** less than everything.

5. Why are 1 and 3 wrong, but 2 and 4 are right?

6. By replacing ONLY the bolded, without rewriting anything else,
how can 1 and 3 be corrected? In other words, what can replace **too**?

Footnote: My thought of writing 'too fewer than 'everyone' [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/23086/8572), motivated the above.

Comment: What in the world is "Albusy"?? (I know there's a link there, but you should explain it in your question)

Comment: @J.R. I apologise for the confusion. Better now?

Comment: *Excessively fewer* sounds rather unusual, too.

Comment: *Albysi* was not used as a modifier (as the OP is using it).

Comment: I might be wrong (I haven't checked), but I think the OP might be thinking of "far fewer", "too few (to consider, for example)", which I think are possible, and mixed them somehow. By the same token, I also believe that "too less (to consider, etc.)" should also be possible, but perhaps it's been taken over by other simpler phrases such as "not enough to".

Comment: @TRomano Thanks. Is there an apter synonym?

Comment: @  Law Area 51 Proposal - Commit: I cannot say what would be apter than *albysi* because I'm not sure what you're trying to say. The question in the title is clear enough (why not 'too less', why not 'too fewer') but I don't know what you want to say with XXXXXX everyone, XXXXX everything.  "Almost everyone|everything?" "Hardly everyone|everything"?

Comment: @TRomano Thanks for the clarification. I removed the *albusy*; I only now realised to compare 1 with 2 and 3 with 4. Better?

Comment: @DamkerngT. Actually, I did think of '"far fewer', which is exactly what I wrote in the post cited in the Footnote. BUT `far fewer' doesn't equate to 'too fewer'. The 'too' criticises the deficiency; 'far' just expresses it neutrally.

Comment: "Far too few" is how to say (grammatically and idiomatically) that the count falls short to an unacceptable degree. "Excessively few" is unidiomatic, and is something of an oxymoron, since "excess" is normally associated with abundance and "overdoing it". "Far fewer" means fewer by a great degree; there is no sense of unacceptability.

Comment: "Excessively less" may be grammatical (FWIW) but it's not idiomatic and again it's jarring semantically, since "excess" connotes overabundance or too much of something."Far less" is the idiomatic way.

Comment: Well, first of all... They're _all_ wrong. So it might be a good idea to ask only why the ones you are interested in (1 and 3) are wrong, without asking us to justify the others (2 and 4) which are also wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Less* and *more* are absolutes.

**Four is less than five.

I'd like less guff out of you, understand? Go to your room and stay there.

More gruel, Sir!**

The bare absolute admits no degree.  Hence, *too less, *too more.

*Fewer* is an absolute as well.  (Cardinality: the count is less).

**There were fewer thanes in the hall after Grendel's visit.**

There are fewer, or there are more, or the count is equal.

Again, the bare absolute admits no degree. Hence, *too fewer.

P.S. Other absolutes:  below, above, after, before, during.

P.P.S.  *too much less, too much more* are a different kettle of fish. There *too* modifies 'much' not 'less|more'.

Answer (score 3):

The degree adverbs *too* and *very* are very restricted in what they can modify. They can modify basic adjectives (*too big*, *very strong*) and adverbs (*too slowly*, *very loudly*), and they can modify a few determiners that are particularly gradable (*too many answers*, *very much confusion*); but they can't modify verbs (**too yelling*, **very running*) or prepositional phrases (**too outside*, **very up*), even though many other adverbs can (*angrily yelling*, *almost outside*).

As you've noticed, *too* can't modify *fewer* and *less*. Similarly, it can't modify *more*, nor comparative adjectives and adverbs like *bigger* or *faster*. (*Very* can't modify any of these, either.)

So instead, we have to say things like *too many fewer* (meaning "fewer by too many") and *too much less* (meaning "less by too much"). Likewise with verbs (*too much yelling*, *very much running*). And with prepositions, we use *far* for the same purpose (*too far outside*, *very far up*).

Comment: This is the interesting sort of thing that I, as a native speaker, have never really thought about and would never know how to explain.

Comment: This is an excellent answer but I disagree about "too many fewer". As a native speaker, I've never seen or heard that construct. Rather than saying, e.g., "Women have too many fewer opportunities than men", you'd say something like "Women have too few opportunities compared to men" or "Women have fewer opportunities than men, to an unacceptable degree." ("Too many fewer" sounds contradictory, too: it seems to raise the question, "How can it be fewer if it's too many?")

Comment: @DavidRicherby: I agree that "too many fewer" is very rare, but I think that that's mostly because what it means is something that we very rarely need to say. (Take your example, "Women have too many fewer opportunities than men". This presupposes that women should have *somewhat* fewer opportunities than men, and is merely objecting to the size of the disparity. Who would ever want to say that? It's not just sexist, it's *complicated*.) This is compounded with the fact that "fewer" is less common than "less", and the end result is that "too many fewer" is very rare.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Regarding your parenthetical note -- I don't think so. After all, you could raise the same spurious objection to "I make much less than she does" ("How can it be less if it's much?").

Comment: @ruakh It doesn't suppose that women *should* have fewer opportunities; just that it might be acceptable for them to have very slightly fewer opportunities. It would hardly be a problem if women had a trillion opportunities and men had a trillion and one, for example. Anyway, it was just an example, not a statement of belief.

Comment: @ruakh I've never heard "too much less", either, so it's not an issue around the rarity of "fewer".

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Re: "it was just an example, not a statement of belief": It was an example *of* a statement of belief. (But don't worry, I'm not accusing *you* of sexism. Just the hypothetical utterer of that sentence.) Re: "I've never heard 'too much less'": You probably have, actually. If you Google it, you'll find that many examples sound natural to you, even though it's hard to intentionally construct a natural-sounding example on your own.

Comment: @ruakh Actually, most of the example from Google, even with "too much less" in quotes, are interrupted by punctuation, e.g., "Don't expect too much... less than 3-star" in a hotel review, "It's all too much! Less junk...". Of the ones that aren't broken by punctuation, the only ones that read naturally to me are in the negative, e.g., "I use less salt but not too much less." To me, that only works because "not too much" is an idiom for "a little".

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Yup, exactly -- just as "not too many" is a quasi-idiom meaning "a few".